# Understanding multi-dimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, web, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a table using multidimensional array's technique but I don't know how to assign the value in the second dimension array.

```
    $str = implode("|",$str);
```

This piece of code represents length of string that contains table name and its column ex. `table1|t1_id , table2|t2_id`

```
    $str = implode("|",$str); 
    $ret = array(array());
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str) ; $i++)
    {
        //Please fill in some code :)
    }

    return $ret;
```

It would be similar to this array structure if you assign it manually

```
    $ret[0][0] = "projects";
    $ret[0][1] = "p_id";
    $ret[1][0] = "tasks";
    $ret[1][1] = "t_id";
```

Comment: What is in `$t` and `$k`? What is your expected output ?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => projects [1] => p_id ) [1] => Array ( [0] => tasks [1] => t_id ) )

Comment: Here's the expected output .Please help

Comment: 1) ^^ Put this into your question 2) What is the input? It's not clear what you have and what you want.

Comment: I have tried nested loop but it prints out the string position!. I expected that if $i[0][0] = 'Project' Then $i[0][1] = "Should be undefined value" But!, it prints out "P" :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but generally you need a for loop in a for loop to initialize a 2 dimensional array:

```
$str = implode("|",$str); 
    $ret = array(array());
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str) ; $i++)
    {
           for ($j = 0; $j < yourCriteria; $j++) 
            {        
              // Now fill in your code
           }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, suppose if I have assigned $K[0][0] = "projects" then $K[0][1] = "Should be undefined right?" But , it prints out "P". The position of character in the first element!